# Issue : Initializer element is not constant on C #define

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, initialization

I am using a `#define` to call a function and get the following gcc error:
**"`error: initializer element is not constant`"** on the directive.

Here, the define directive:

```
#define HASH(STRING_VALUE) (lookup_hash(STRING_VALUE))
```

Function implementation:

```
static inline uint32_t lookup_hash(const char *str)
{
    uint32_t hash = 5381;
    int32_t c;

    while ((c = *str++))
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Function call example:

```
static const asr_handlerTree_t asr_LT_nwk_orders[]=
{
    {HASH("link"), NULL, asr_link_funct},
    {HASH("unlink"), NULL, asr_unlink_funct},

    //  Used at runtime to determinate table limit, keep at table tail
    {(uint32_t) 0, NULL, NULL}
};
```

Why gcc compiler raise the issue as directive calls should only be replaced by function  at pre-processing ?

---

Update: Add structure declaration following answer feedbacks:

```
typedef struct _asr_handlerTree_type_
{
    const uint32_t hashedIntent_u32;
    const asr_handlerTree_t * branchs;
    const funct_t Func;
} asr_handlerTree_t;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables with *static storage duration*, i.e. those declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword, can only be initialized with *constant expressions*.  This means you can't use the values of other variables (although you can use their addresses) or make function calls.

You would need to initialize this particular field with a dummy value, then have a function that is called at the start of `main` that assigns the values that need to be set at runtime.

```
static const asr_handlerTree_t asr_LT_nwk_orders[]=
{
    {0, NULL, asr_link_funct},
    {0, NULL, asr_unlink_funct},

    //  Used at runtime to determinate table limit, keep at table tail
    {(uint32_t) 0, NULL, NULL}
};

void set_hashes()
{
    asr_LT_nwk_orders[0].hash = HASH("link");
    asr_LT_nwk_orders[1].hash = HASH("unlink");
}
```

Comment: Extensions such as GCC's `__attribute__((constructor))` can also be used to perform "pre-execution" initialization before `main()` is called.

Comment: @dbush : Thanks a lot for your initialization proposal. Let's keep going coding... Cheers

Answer (score 5):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
> literals.

And this array with static storage duration

```
static const asr_handlerTree_t asr_LT_nwk_orders[]=
{
    {HASH("link"), NULL, asr_link_funct},
    {HASH("unlink"), NULL, asr_unlink_funct},

    //  Used at runtime to determinate table limit, keep at table tail
    {(uint32_t) 0, NULL, NULL}
};
```

is not initialized with constant expressions. The function `lookup_hash` is called at run-time. So the compiler issues an error.

Comment: @fofolevrai No at all. You are welcome.:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to initialize a constant array with a runtime function's return value, which is impossible to do by the compiler because it is not going to execute the code.

It would help to see the asr_handlerTree_t type definition, but I think you might be better served by storing pointers to that function instead?

Comment: It is unimportant whether the array is constant or not.

Comment: @DarkFranX : Thanks a lot for pointing out the issue so quickly!